# Deploy of ejb client to nexus

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

I'm using the maven-ejb-plugin (version 2.5.1) to generate a ejb-client. The generation works fine, but when I want to deploy to nexus

```
mvn deploy ejb:ejb
```

it only deploys the ejb itself:
[image]

the log shows the deployment of the ejb and the generation in the target folder of the ejb and the client

I configured the plugin to generate a client jar, what it does on install

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>org.infinispan export</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <clientIncludes>
                    <clientInclude>santam/apps/staticlookups/model/**</clientInclude>
                    <clientInclude>santam/apps/staticlookups/services/**</clientInclude>
                </clientIncludes>
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Usually you shouldn't call the goal of the ejb. It should be part of the build via mvn deploy simply...Do you have set packaging `ejb` ? Have you configured to create a an ejb-client ?

Comment: I tried calling just deploy, and tried to run deploy from the parent folder (instead of the EJB subfolder), that results in the ear and war also being deployed to nexus. But still no client.jar...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks khmarbaise, your comment got my line of thinking right to find the answer.
There were two issues:

1. Set the packaging type defined in the pom.xml to ejb, the package lifecycle phase can then be used instead of the ejb:ejb goal
2. The order of execution of the plugins, you first have to package the client jar and then deploy to archive or install it.

Solution

1. Update the EJB pom

> ```
> <project>
>     ...
>     <packaging>ejb</packaging>
> ```

2. By default if you execute the deploy goal it will first package and then deploy (or install to deploy to local .m2 folder)

> ```
>  mvn deploy
> ```